Mono (mono-devel) for Ubuntu 24.04/noble?
What is the status of the Mono (.NET framework programming environment) on Ubuntu 24.04/noble?
I am a little worried to discover that the Mono project download page does not seem to cover anything newer than Ubuntu 20.04.
I thought I would try my luck anyway, and make an educated guess to update the repo line to:
https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-noble main

…but it looks as though a noble section of the repo doesn't exist:
Ign:8 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-noble InRelease
Err:9 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-noble Release
  404  The specified blob does not exist. [IP: 13.107.246.64 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support ca-certificates-mono cli-common libexif12 libgdiplus libmono-2.0-dev
  libmono-accessibility4.0-cil libmono-btls-interface4.0-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil

…although it looks like it is going to manage to go on to install the packages from "somewhere" in the repo anyway?

I have Ubuntu 24.04 desktop, I install mono using debian sable release.
All instructions detailed in their official site.
So install requirements if you didn't before
sudo apt install dirmngr ca-certificates gnupg

Add gpg key and repo.
sudo gpg --homedir /tmp --no-default-keyring --keyring \
/usr/share/keyrings/mono-official-archive-keyring.gpg \
--keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \ 
--recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mono-official-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list

Update
sudo apt update

then install it
sudo apt install mono-complete

That's it
